# An easy science/nerd riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, science

```
My mother is the sea and sky, my father's of the earth,
When those two come together, all but destined is my birth,

I grow so much larger than the substance I consume,
To one of the avengers, my existence could spell doom,

I could spread like pox across the surface of a giant,
The giant might then wish that his skin was a bit more pliant.
```

**What am I?**

Comment: Is the `science` tag obligatory ?

Comment: @ABcDexter After quickly googling obligatory, I can confirm... that I still don't know exactly what you mean.  The science tag fits though I believe.  Even if the level of scientific knowledge required is quite low.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you perhaps

> Rust?

My mother is the sea and sky, my father's of the earth,

When those two come together, all but destined is my birth,

> Rust comes from iron (earth) and the oxygen (sky)... can be fuelled by moisture (sea).

I grow so much larger than the substance I consume,

To one of the avengers, my existence could spell doom,

> Rust 'consumes' iron, would definitely be harmful to iron man.

I could spread like pox across the surface of a giant,

The giant might then wish that his skin was a bit more pliant.

> Rust occurs on even the biggest iron objects, such as a ship.

Science tag:

> Rust is general knowledge, though it is written as a chemical equation and studied as such.

Comment: I am!  This is Correct!  +1

Comment: Good answer, I was thinking of something similar but this sloppy android app, and yes [some suits of Iron Man are water proof](http://ironman.wikia.com/wiki/Mark_VI) :P

Comment: I was just playing with words.  I don't imagine Stark would wear anything likely to rust. :)

Comment: I know this is old, but wasn't the giant reference referring to [The Iron Giant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Iron_Giant)? I don't see anyone mentioning that.

Answer (score 2):

> Could the answer be clouds aswell.

My mother is the sea and sky, my father's of the earth,
When those two come together, all but destined is my birth,

> earth, sea and sky are all involved in cloud formation or birth.

I grow so much larger than the substance I consume,

> Clouds are less dense than water.

To one of the avengers, my existence could spell doom,

> First test with iron man's suit

I could spread like pox across the surface of a giant,

> clouds are seen of surface of planets (giants) and can look like disease.

The giant might then wish that his skin was a bit more pliant.

> The planet may be better off with less clouds?

Answer (score 1):

> mood

My mother is the sea and sky, my father's of the earth,

> Your mood is influenced by both the weather and the events that happen on earth

When those two come together, all but destined is my birth,

> You have a mood

I grow so much larger than the substance I consume,

> Your mood can change radically from a small incident

To one of the avengers, my existence could spell doom,

> Hulk change with his mood, doom can be used to spell mood

I could spread like pox across the surface of a giant,

> Even giants are sensitive to mood changes

The giant might then wish that his skin was a bit more pliant.

> He wish to have a toughter skin

Comment: I'm not looking for "mood" but some good fits there.

Answer (score -2):

the answer to the above question is:

> RUST.

Comment: You should explain answers and use spoiler formatting.